# what is different between npm run build and next build also npm run export and next export

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, next.js

in my next project i want to create a static build for production . so i referred the tutorial . they are saying next build and next export . i did that . but when i next build i got an error like this . [image]

but when i hit `npm run build` . there is no errors . it gives me a build folder . why it's like this ? how can i solve this error .?

sorry for my poor English

Comment: `npm run build` will run whatever command you have in the `build` script inside your `package.json` file. Usually, in a Next.js project the build script would be `"build": "next build"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `next build` is to get more specific output from NextJS. You can read more in Next JS Documentation -> Deployment Section, or you can visit this link https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment